# Google SS: how to make a self-altering cell value for memoizing dates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[*Crossposted @ Google SS forums*](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/desktop/TXmUr4pz4i0)

I want do do this:

```js
function memoizeDate(condition) {
  if (condition) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    cell.setValue(Date.now());
  }
}
```

So that in (say) cell `C2`, if you set its value to `=memoizeDate(eq(b2,"foo"))`, then as soon as `b2` gets changed, `C2` changes itself to the memoized value.

However, I get a "You do not have permission to call setValue" error, and I'm also not sure if the "active" cell (from the script's POV) is the one from which the script was called (i.e. `C2`) rather than who knows what else (`B2`? whatever random thing might be selected by the user?).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried like this (suggestion) :

```
function memoizeDate(condition) {
  if (condition) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    return new Date();
  }else{
    return 'nop or whatever'
  }
}
```

---

EDIT following your comment : I keep reading your question and comments but I'm not sure what you really want to do.

On one hand you say "*overriding the function itself*" which means in fact returning a value (and that's what my code does) and on the other hand you *try to get the active cell* which is the one the user is editing (B2 in your example) and in that case you simply **can't do that** , please read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions?hl=fr-FR#using) about custom function :

***Custom functions return values, but they cannot set values outside the cells they are in. In most circumstances, a custom function in cell A1 cannot modify cell A5. However, if a custom function returns a double array, the results overflow the cell containing the function and fill the cells below and to the right of the cell containing the custom function. You can test this with a custom function containing return [[1,2],[3,4]];.***

All in all I think this question is rather unclear, (no personal offense) you should try to reformulate it at the least.

Comment: That doesn't memoize, it returns the *current* date (i.e. whenever you look at it, not whenever the condition was first true). I want it to be that, once set, its value is permanent.

Comment: I suggested that code just to solve your issue about not being able to write to the cell... the function itself is a copy/paste of your own code so I'm afraid you voted yourself down :-) if you want to keep the date in memory you should store is somewhere else, there are plenty of ways to accomplish that but it wasn't the point of your post.

Comment: Actually, it was. Note the difference between trying to set the value *of the cell we are currently in* (i.e. overriding the function itself), which is what my code does, vs merely outputting the current date, which is what yours does.

Comment: That's the thing. I want to *set the value* of the cell it's called on, i.e. to replace the function itself with its value - rather than to continually output the new value. If you have another idea for how to have memoization, do tell. ;-)

Comment: Custom function will not be the way to go as they can't "setFormula" (and obviously trying to replace themselves with something else is not allowed), they can only return values. The functionality you are looking for should probably be handled in an onEdit triggered script.

Comment: Could one make an onEdit script that works generically? E.g. looking for a custom function which itself does nothing and making it happen? I don't want to have to make onEdits for each thing; I want to be able to reuse it easily, same as any other in-spreadsheet function.